# The "union" of matrices

Tags: matrices

I have three matrices, $A$, $B$ and $C$, in which elements are zero or one. I create a matrix $D$ in which $D(i,j)=1$ if at least one of the following elements ($A(i,j)$, $B(i,j)$ and $C(i,j)$) are equal to one. Is there a specific name for this kind of union of matrices?

Thanks

P.

Comment: Pointwise OR.  $D_{i,j} = 1 - (1-A_{i,j})(1-B_{i,j})(1-C_{i,j})$